# Why are some links ignored / not captured / seen in iframe.getElementsByTagName("a")?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to get all links in a webpage, even in its iframes:

```
function GetTheLinks()
{
    var linksArray = [];
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var iLinksCount = links.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < iLinksCount; i++)
    {
        var link = links[i];
        linksArray.push(link.innerHTML);
        linksArray.push(link.innerText);
        linksArray.push(link.href);
    }
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    var iFramesCount = frames.length;
    for (var f = 0; f < iFramesCount; f++)
    {
        var doc = frames[f].contentDocument;
        if (doc)
        {
             links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
             alert(links.length + " links in frame " + f);
             var iLinksCount = links.length;
             for (var i = 0; i < iLinksCount; i++)
             {
                 var link = links[i];
                 linksArray.push(link.innerHTML);
                 linksArray.push(link.innerText);
                 linksArray.push(link.href);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             alert("Error!");
         }
    }
    return linksArray;
}
```

I am confronted with an URL where my code does not catch a certain link.
The URL is [this one](https://www.zeit.de/zustimmung?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeit.de%2Findex).

The link that I want to catch is this one:

[image]

Using Chrome's dev tools, I can see that it is contained in a frame.

What am I doing wrong in my code so that it doesn't catch this link?

Thank you!

There is its code:

```
<a href="https://premium.zeit.de/bestellung/1932788?angebot=https%3A%2F%2Fpremium.zeit.de%2Fbestellung%2F1932788&amp;entry_service=pur&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeine.zeit.de%2Fbestellung_abschliessen%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.zeit.de%252Findex" class="option__button option__button--pur js-forward-link-purabo" data-encode-level="1" data-ct-label="purabo_button">
                                    <span class="visually-hidden">zeit.de Pur: </span>Jetzt abonnieren
                                </a>
```

Comment: *`frames[f].getElementsByTagName("a")`* gets the children elements of that frame element, but it won't have any. If you want the links inside the document that the iframe embeds into the page, you'll need to use [`frames[f].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument), but notice that it might not be accessible

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I missed that, but in my code, it was present. I have edited my post. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean by "not accessible"?

Comment: You can’t read the content of frames that aren’t on the same origin (i.e. that don’t belong to you).

Comment: @Ry- Can you tell me what you mean exactely, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: @RoToRa But as far as I can see, the iframe is coming from the same domain (zeit.de), isn't it?

Comment: @Ry Also, I am not getting any except. It's just that frames[f].getElementsByTagName("a").length = 0.